Как ограничить создание объектов класса на C++
Всем привет, начал писать небольшой движок, чисто для себя и для получения опыта в разработке на C++. Я захотел написать API/Framework (не знаю как точно сказать), чтобы мне было удобно работать с ним. Нынешняя задумка заключалась в том, чтобы написать статические классы движка (Builder, Worker, Destroyer и другие) для того, чтобы каждый отвечал за свою задачу. Пораскинув мозгами, решил написать сразу static class Builder..., однако при компиляции проекта увидел предупреждения о том, что static пропускается, решил вообще загуглить про статичные классы на C++ и информации о конкретно static class нигде не оказалось, как я понял их привычное понимание не предусмотрено в C++ (17). Есть догадка по поводу того, что просто делать все переменные и функции static и конструктор класса запульнуть в private, но не знаю насколько это хороший вариант. Я не хочу, чтобы была возможность создавать экземпляров таких классов, мне понравилась философия создания объектов на Vulkan, в нем изначально есть функции по типу vkCreateInstance, в которую закидывается информации и уже по ссылке на созданный VkInstance, функция сама закидывает в объект все нужное. Возможно я как-то размыто объяснил, если нужна какая-то информация дайте знать.
P.S. Пример кода. Также если есть предложения о том, как можно было организовать функционал движка, советы и прочее, я был бы рад их узнать
#include "engine.hpp"
using namespace Engine;

int main() {

    // Я хочу делать так, обращаться к методам, чтобы не создавать экземпляры класса
    Builder::Build();
    Worker::MainThread(); 
    Destroyer::Destroy(); 
    return 0;

    // И не хочу делать так, то есть запретить это

    Builder* temp = new Builder();
}

P.S. (2) Вот какая философия сейчас в моем коде:
Engine.cpp
#include "engine.hpp"
using namespace Engine;

#include "window.hpp"
using namespace Window;

#include "vulkan.hpp"
using namespace Vulkan;

void Builder::Build() {
    WindowManager::Init();
    VulkanManager::Init();
}

void Worker::MainThread() {
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(WindowManager::GetWindow())) {
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
}

void Destroyer::Destroy() {
    WindowManager::Destroy();
    VulkanManager::Destroy();
}

Также вот пример кода заголовочных файлов, я стараюсь писать эту "базу" во всех headers:
window_manager.hpp
#ifndef WINDOW_HPP
#define WINDOW_HPP

#pragma once
#include "std_include.hpp"

namespace Window {
    class WindowManager {
    public:
        static void Init();
        static void Destroy();
        static GLFWwindow* GetWindow();
        static const uint32_t GetWindowWidth();
        static const uint32_t GetWindowHeight();

    private:
        static inline GLFWwindow* _Window;
        static const uint32_t WIDTH = 1280;
        static const uint32_t HEIGHT = 720;
    };
}

#endif


Alex F, условно да, а может так и есть, я бы хотел создавать синглтон, один объект, использовать его методы и свойства из любой точки кода и прочее. Но как создавать их я не знаю, а может не помню, за год все позабывал

Может, вам нужны namespaceы?...

Harry, namespaceЫ я уже использую, к сожалению это не то :O

Alex F, да похоже я не ясно указал названия :O, 'Destroeyr::Destroy()'отвечает за закрытие всех компонентов Vulkan и окна GLFW, удаляет все Instance, DebugMessenger и прочее что есть в Vulkan, а также закрывает окно. Предполагалось мной написать дополнительный функционал, чтобы вызывать отдельно удаления всего что создаю, сейчас внесу правку того, что сейчас есть

Alex F, правки внес, если что-то из кода не понятно, то идея в том, чтобы в каждом статическом классе был инициализатор, дестроер и методы обращения к классу. Синглтоны я писал на C#, думаю с C++ похожий случай, сейчас погляжу, как это можно реализовать. Однако, все равно мой код не работает и синглтоны ситуацию не поменяют :D

А чем это отличается от namespaceов? Что вы хотите такого, что не реализуемо через них?

Alex F, думаю в этом есть доля правды, после моих ответов похоже вопрос переквалифировал себя в другое русло. Но все же я не считаю, что хочу создать именно библиотеку для создания окна, конечно есть цель в том, чтобы создать окно, но я хочу создать движок, чтобы я могу создавать различные объекты, загружать текстуры, настроить физику и прочее :D

Думаю, вопрос исчерпан, из-за моей неопределенности, я лучше сам поищу информацию на просторах интернета, пока не найду "золото", если кто-то уже писал движки "под себя", можете поделиться реализацией здесь, если не сложно, это даст некоторую точку опоры :]

"Вот какая философия сейчас в моем коде:" это называется "глобальные переменнные". Собственно "оболочку" из класса со всей static мишурой можно спокойно выкинуть, в С++ же не запрещено писать функции вне класса. Получится прям ламповая non-reentrant программа С-style из 80-х
